# Add web reference to silverlight application

Tags: c#, silverlight, reference, web

I'm new to silverlight, I want to add web reference to silverlight application is that possable???

I can only add service reference to the SilverightApplication but i want to add web reference.

I can add web reference to the SilverightApplication.Web, can i use it from SilverightApplication??

I aslo can add service reference to the SilverightApplication but functions of service reference has no return value so i cant recieve the data, here is the code
Service1SoapClient c = new Service1SoapClient();

```
        ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient a = new  ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient();
        a.returnStr_19_9Async("");
```

the function returnStr_19_9Async("") has no return value can any one please tell me what is teh wrong??
Can you please tell me how, please explain..

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try adding the service reference instead? It should work.

Comment: well, I can add service reference but i dont know how to use it, can you explain please

Comment: the problem with the service reference is that it has no return value function, so i cant use it to recive the web data..this is actully the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem you may be striking is that WCF calls are all done asynchronously in Silverlight. This means when you call your initial service function (let's call it `GetMyClient(int clientId)` ), the proxy that you have generated will have a function called `GetMyClientAsync()`, and it will also have an event called `GetMyClientCompleted` which you must subscribe to:

```
myProxy.GetMyClientCompleted += new EventHandler<GetMyClientCompletedEventArgs>(MyProxy_GetMyClientCompleted);
```

that event handler will look something like this:

```
private void MyProxy_GetMyClientCompleted(object sender, GetMyClientCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //e.Result will have your returned values
}
```

This is just a very brief overview that gives you enough to get started. You could also read more here: [Silverlight.net | Data & Networking | Network Services (Soap, REST and More)](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/data-networking/network-services-%28soap,-rest-and-more%29)